# Reactive Backend Calls - How to get IDs / Names /

Tags: angular, rest, rxjs

Minimal Stackblitz Repo to follow along: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angulare-backend-calls-so

Assume I have a Backend which provides me with my data, in this case a simple counter with an ID.

```
{id: number, counter: number}
```

And i would like to display the received value in my `app.component.html` with help of the `async` pipe so i dont create any unnecessary subscriptions.

After some time the user decides to increase the counter, now I need an ID so the Backend knows which counter object to increase. But since i cant access it directly this isn't so easy. And i don't want to `.pipe(first())` subscribe just to make the call.

One approach to solve this would be to change the method signature inside the `app.component` to also take the counter ID and pass it from inside the template. But I don't see this approach working if I'm not using `*ngIf="(obs$ | async) as obs"` because I would have to subscribe to the counter object observable again with another `async` pipe inside the `(click)` (or whatever) handler, or is this the intended behavior / best practice ? And what would happen if I'm depending on multiple streams `(click)=copyTimer((counter1|async).id, (counter2|async).id)` surely cant be the optimal solution

**First question** therefore: What is the best approach to handle ID-dependant backend calls when using streams as main source of data?

Let's skip some time ahead and assume the server got the ID correctly and increased the counter accordingly. How would I handle updating the view? 
The thing I did was to just return the complete counter object from the backend, which might work for this specific minimal example, but would get out of hand if using more complex objects (I assume).

I could obviously just use `this.countingObj = this.appService.increaseCounter(id)` but a second component would miss out on these updates, therefore the update needs to happen inside the service.

**Second question**: Should I keep a BehaviorSubject inside the service, which tracks changes and functions as a proxy for get-calls aswell, or how would the app-wide change of an object be noticed so it's consistent within all components?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Behavior Subject to handle the action stream of my increment function.

First, of course you need to have the data loaded first, before you can decide to increase the count of an object, it doesn't make sense and your async pipe subscription will handle the listening to the stream and on each new emit, will update the UI.

Second, you merge both of your streams (data stream - the one responsible for streaming the list of your objects) and action stream (the increment action stream), I use combineLatest for this specific scenario because It suits the requirements (need both values before we emit), don't worry, since action stream is a behavior subject, you don't need an action for the observable to emit the value,  we have null as initial value and then we ignore null id during the map function. 
Your multiple components will subscribe to this merged stream (using async pipe) and then you can loop through your objects (original stackblitz was object, i made it list), each time a user click increment, you pass the id to the action stream, which will emit a new id value to be incremented, using your map function, we increment the count, and then a new value will be emitted to our combinedObservable (dataWithAction$),  then your view will detect the new emitted value, and will be automatically updated, this will work across any component which is listening to your (dataWithAction$).

Simple code (again, i modified the object observable to stream a list instead of single object to make it clearer example)

Service

```
incrementSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(null);
 incrementAction$ = this.incrementSubject.asObservable();
 data$ = of([{id: 0,counter: 0},{id: 1,counter: 0}]);
 dataWithAction$ = combineLatest([this.incrementAction$,this.data$]).pipe(
   map(([id,data])=> {
     if(id !== null){
     data.find(t => t.id == id).counter++
     }
     return data;
   }));
  constructor() { }
  increaseCounter(id: number) {
    this.incrementSubject.next(id);
  }
```

your component .ts

```
   countingObj: Observable<{ id: number; counter: number }[]>;

   constructor(private appService: AppService) {
    this.countingObj = this.appService.dataWithAction$;
   }

   increaseCounter(id) {
    this.appService.increaseCounter(id);
   }
```

View

```
<div *ngIf="countingObj | async as obj">
    <div *ngFor='let x of obj'>
        <div>{{x.counter}}</div>
        <div>{{x.id}}</div>
        <button (click)=increaseCounter(x.id)> Increment  </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

RxJS Advanced Patterns – Operate Heavily Dynamic UI’s | Michael Hladky talk is highly recommended

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm partially satisfied. How would I get the data from Backend? Should I have a method which requests the data and then appends it to the data subject? That would mean I would have to subscribe inside a Service which I thought is a no-no.

Comment: Replace your data$ of observable with an http get, that's all, no need to subscribe your view already subscribe

Comment: But this way if some e.g. components get initialized after I would have to redo the http call, although i already did it before.

Comment: You can use [share operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/share) to avoid this multiple calls.

Comment: But that would not work if they are seperste from each other and both access a getData() method inside a Service which simply Returns a shared observable. I would have to store the request some where and I'm unsure how tk achieve this.

Comment: There is no method, again you replace your data$ observable with an http call (no need for a function), pipe it with share operator

Comment: Exactly - suppose I have 1 Service, 2 Components. Both need the data$ from backend. 
So having a method return http.get(..).pipe(share()) will result in 2 backend calls if both componets access the service directly. And I'm trying to prevent unnecessary server communication.

Comment: ok then you can use shareReplay, I guess this will achieve what you want.

Comment: I think none of the sharing operators works for that case. Because the Observable gets instantiated with every call. I would have to save the reference to earlier calls somewhere and return it within the method. - Thats what Question 2 is referring too. Thanks for the advice nevertheless.